# zend_call_method_with_N_params

Tags: php, c, php-extension, zend-framework

There are `zend_call_method_with_0_params`, `zend_call_method_with_1_params` and `zend_call_method_with_2_params` in PHP extension development.

But how to call method with more than 2 params?

Comment: I think you can't. You should use the get request. The url is build like this: `http://example.com/param1/param2/get_name1/get_value1/get_name2/get_value2`

Comment: unfortunately I have to call `parent::__construct` method which takes 3 parameters and get request won't help, because parent class is standard Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong. You have to use `zend_call_function directly`. See the body of  [`zend_call_method`](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_interfaces.c#zend_call_method). Basically you have to prepare a `zend_fcall_info` object first. The number of arguments should be stored in the `fci.param_count` field and `fci.params` should have an array with `fci.param_count` elements.