# Is it possible to use function of one php extension in other?

Tags: php, c++

I want to make a php C++ extension. Is it possible to use redis functions into my PHP C++ extension?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but might be valuable, if you add details about what you are trying to achieve, and any research you have done on this subject.

Comment: Eg: 
I want to connect to redis using PhpRedis from my extension.

Comment: @Niteshmorajkar The subject is very technical. If you want a good answer then you should *edit the question* and explain it in greater detail.

Comment: I agree with @ppeterka - this could be very interesting, but we tend to encourage a bit more prior research and a bit more detail. Would you edit the question to explain what you have done to research this, and why you need it?

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? Why not just use redis C API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call php method by calling [`zend_call_method_with_0_params`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_interfaces.h#43), [`zend_call_method_with_1_params`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_interfaces.h#46) or [`zend_call_method_with_2_params`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_interfaces.h#49) macros. For instance, like this:

```
zend_call_method_with_2_params(&this, ZF_G(ce_exception_ptr)->parent, NULL, ZEND_CONSTRUCTOR_FUNC_NAME, &parent_return_value, msg_zval, code_zval TSRMLS_CC);
```

If you need to call a function with more then 2 params see my question: [zend_call_method_with_N_params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586996/zend-call-method-with-n-params)